# How to dynamically gray out a slider?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, output, display, slider

Here's a very simple MWE to show my problem :

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[a t^2 - b t, {t, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    {{a, 1, Style["Parameter 1", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01},
    {{b, 1, Style["Parameter 2", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01}
]
```

This code produces a simple graphics with two sliders : parameters $a$ and $b$.

I would like to make the second slider to become all *grayed out* (i.e. unavailable, with $b$ set to 0) if the user moves the first slider to $a  \le 0$.

How to achieve this ?  This is certainly very basic (?) but I'm yet unable to see how.

Comment: To grey out the slider, add `Enabled -> Dynamic[a > 0]` as an option to the `b` variable specification.

Comment: @lowriniak, wow !  It works perfectly.  However, the $b$ parameter should turn to 0.  How to add this constraint ?

Comment: Aah !  This actually solves totally my problem !  I suggest that you write a small answer with the code, so I could mark it (and you get more reputation points) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to expand a little on my comment, to make a slider be greyed out you can use `Enabled`:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[a t^2 - b t, {t, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    {{a, 1, Style["Parameter 1", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01},
    {{b, 1, Style["Parameter 2", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01, Enabled -> False}
]
```

[image: Enabled->False]

From the tutorial [AdvancedManipulateFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html), see the section Interdependent Controls - this shows some examples of controls depending on each other.  This means we can use `a` in the definition of `b`:

*Note: in my comment I added a `Dynamic` which I don't think was strictly necessary*

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[a t^2 - b t, {t, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    {{a, 1, Style["Parameter 1", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01},
    {{b, 1, Style["Parameter 2", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01, Enabled -> (a > 0)}
]
```

[image: Above0] [image: Below0]

If you wanted more dependence on `a`, it is fairly easy to just use `If` statements in the body of your code:

```
Manipulate[
    If[a < 0, b = 0];
    Plot[a t^2 - b t, {t, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    {{a, 1, Style["Parameter 1", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01},
    {{b, 1, Style["Parameter 2", 10]}, -10, 10, 0.01, Enabled -> (a > 0)}
]
```

Comment: Apparently, the **Dynamic** command need to be there for my code to properly work.  Without it, the slider isn't grayed out.  Strange, since your code DO work !